# Xcode acting weird

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

Xcode is acting very strange. It is grabbing from parse when I did not specify it to do so. My cellforRow method is empty and it is still showing data in the cells. Anyone know why this happens? H

Comment: Did you try ⌘-Shift-K to clean the project? Do so and then build it by ⌘-B, and then run it again by the Play button at top left corner of Xcode screen.

Comment: Unless you've installed some strange plugin, Xcode is most certainly not talking to parse at all.  The only thing potentially taking to Parse is code, which you've written, and failed to include here.

Answer (score 0):

The data is saved offline as well when using parse. So when you first simulate your app it will fetch data and when you again run that app again in simulator it will show you the last loaded data from server. 
Try deleting the app from simulator and then press command+shift+k, it will solve your problem.